# Django: Unable to set background-image to a button in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to set a background-image to a button but its not displayed. In the inpect element when I hover over the background url it displays the image. Meaning the url is correct.

```
<button style="background-image: url('{{  mobile_brand.image.url }}'); !important;
           background-repeat: no-repeat;" 
           name="brand" id="brand" class="btn btn-outline-info m-1" 
           type="submit" value={{mobile_brand}}></button>
```

I have tried different variations like using input instead of button. Putting static in the url. Removing comas, background-repeat. And tried giving the full path. Nothing works.
Thankyou for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it by using

```
           <button name="brand" id="brand" class="btn btn-outline-info m-1" 
           type="submit" value={{mobile_brand}}>{{mobile_brand}}
           <img class='brand-btn-icon' src={{mobile_brand.image.url}}/>
           </button>
```

Feels stupid now but sometimes its hard to figure out easy things. Thanks